# captcha in codeigniter create 2 images at the same time

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

The problem is if the method has a parameter like

> function index($product_id) {

the captcha creates 2 images at the same time and make my inputcode and captcha code miss match always but if i remove the parameter like

> function index() {

the captcha create 1 image only and my inputcode and captcha code matched each other... but i need to put parameter in my index() so that i can pass value from a tag from views to controller. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

**Eidt_product.php**

```
class Edit_product extends CI_Controller {

function index($product_id) {
      $msg = "Submit the word you see below:";

             // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
            'img_width'     => '150',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'word_length'   => 5,
            'font_size'     => 16
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);
        $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
        $data['captcha_msg'] = $msg;

        // $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        // $data['row'] = $this->db->get('tbl_products')->row();
        $this->load->view('edit_product_form', $data);


    }
    }
```